# How to set dynamically model class to Retrofit requests?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

In my application i want use **Retrofit2** library for requests and i want set **dynamically** response model, i don't want set model into `interface` model!
**For example :** 
**My interface method is :**

```
@GET("api/server?mode=supports")
Call<SupportListResponse> getSupport_List(@Header("jwt") String token);
```

I don't want set `SupportListResponse` into `Call<>` , i want set this model **dynamically** from `Activity`/`Fragment` class!

How can i set **general model** class **instead of** `SupportListResponse` ?

**My activity full code :**

```
public class TimerRecyclerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProgressBar timerProgressBar;
    private List<Today> model = new ArrayList<>();
    private Adapter adapter;
    private ApiInterface api;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer_recycler);

        api = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), model);
        adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.timerRecyclerView);
        timerProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.timerProgressBar);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Call<AuctionsListResponse> call = api.getMainAuctions("", 1, 10);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<AuctionsListResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AuctionsListResponse> call, Response<AuctionsListResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body().getRes() != null) {
                        if (response.body().getRes().getToday().size() > 0) {
                            timerProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            model.clear();
                            model.addAll(response.body().getRes().getToday());
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AuctionsListResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can i it?

Comment: you want to get just json response so that you can make model class according to your requirement?

Comment: Get the response in string and then based on some value in the response parse it into appropriate model class.

Comment: @007, yes my bro. can you help me? please

Comment: The generics equivalent would be (declaration) Call<T> <T> getSupport_List(@Header("jwt") String token); So you can infer by using Call<AnyObj> call = calls.<AnyObj>getSupport)List("") but I think retrofit uses aapt to generate code so your problem is not about typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do Some modification in your code

```
   @GET("api/server?mode=supports")
    Call<ResponseBody> getSupport_List(@Header("jwt") String token);
```

while getting retrofit object

```
   public static Retrofit getWorkbook() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

in main Activity Retrofit

```
    private void gettingResponseFromRetrofit() {
            ApiInterface api = ApiClient.getWhatsNew().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<ResponseBody> call = api.getSupport_List("", 1, 10);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        try {
                            // here you will get the response
                            // do your stuff
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error Occur", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, i want set `SupportListResponse` into **Activity** code. such as : `Call<AuctionsListResponse> call = api.getMainAuctions("", 1, 10);` . how can i it?

Comment: response.body().string(); you can convert your response to string. And then parse the json according to your requirement

Comment: I write in code into activity : `Call<AuctionsListResponse> call = api.getMainAuctions("", 1, 10);` . but when use your code show me error for this code : `Call<AuctionsListResponse> call = api.getMainAuctions("", 1, 10);`

Comment: how can i it? can you help me?

Comment: Thanks for update your question my dear bro, but i updated my question and i added activity full codes. can you see it and help me with my above codes? please. because i am amateur and really need your help. please . thanks

Comment: yea i just give you the retrofit code which you want to implement in you main activity

Comment: I update my question, please see and help me. please :(

Comment: are you here? can you help me?

Comment: change this line  Call<AuctionsListResponse> call = api.getMainAuctions("", 1, 10);  to  Call<ResponseBody> call = api.getMainAuctions("", 1, 10);